# Performance: UIView in a UIView or replace the UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to have a main UIView take care of adding one of multiple UIViews as a subview. Since only one subview is active at any time, and the subview completely covers the main view, I might as well replace the main view. But this takes some effort, and I'm not sure if it would be worth the small gain in performance. Am I going to see any difference at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they full-screen views? If so, then you could use `UIViewController` to do the management.

Comment: Yes they're full-screen views. I should have thought of using the view controller. Thanks!